# Returning value from a Parse function in swift

Tags: swift, database, uitableview, parse-platform, return

I want to return a value from a parse function in swift but I'm running into a problem...
When I try to return the value in the function I get "Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to closure result type '()'"

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    let query = PFQuery(className: "people")
    query.countObjectsInBackground
    { (count, error) in
        
        return Int(count)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a closure and `numberOfRowsInSection` takes an `Int`.

I am not really sure what is the logic behind but what you can do is:

```
// declare this variable 
var numberOfSections:Int?

// then inside a function or viewDidLoad
let query = PFQuery(className: "people")
query.countObjectsInBackground
{ (count, error) in
    self.numberOfSections = Int(count)
    // finally you force the tableView to reload
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
   return numberOfSections ?? 0 
  // maybe you want to return at least one section when 
 //  you var is nil so can can change it to ?? 1
}
```